# The system cannot infer the transport information from URL WSO2EI

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Please, I have this error with my WSO2EI API definitions, it worked for me many times but no I don't know what is happening.

[image]

My Configuration is as following :

```
<resource methods="PUT DELETE GET" uri-template="/{appointmentId}">
    <inSequence>
        <log description="" level="custom">
            <property expression="uri.var.appointmentId" name="property_name"/>
        </log>
        <switch description="" source="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD">
            <case regex="GET">
                <sequence key="appointmentGet"/>
            </case>
 <default>
                <sequence key="errorSequence"/>
            </default>
        </switch>
        <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence>
        <sequence key="errorSequence"/>
        <send/>
    </faultSequence>
</resource>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to use get-property('uri.var.appointmentId')